# react dynamic component type example

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How/Where can i add types to the dynamic component `Icons[name]` ?

```
import * as Icons from "react-icons/fa";

const DynamicFaIcon = ({ name }: any) => {
  const IconComponent = Icons[name];

  return <IconComponent />;
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could just grap the keys from the import, since its a JS object like any other:

```
import * as Icons from "react-icons/fa";

const DynamicFaIcon = ({ name }: {name: keyof typeof Icons}) => {
  const IconComponent = Icons[name];

  return <IconComponent />;
};
```

I would be careful about importing literally everything from that package though. There's over 1,500 components in there, does *any* application actually make use of all of them? You'll end up bundling way more than you need.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer! The icon name is going to be a string, so this is a problem again `<DynamicFaIcon name={icon} />` ... Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"Fa500Px" | "FaAccessibleIcon" ....

Comment: And yes it's a problem loading the whole library. I tried using a `loadable` solution like this one, https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamiciconload-react-icons-6imgv?file=/src/DynamicIcon.tsx , but had other typescript issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer on [dynamic icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070236/how-to-add-font-awesome-icon-to-react-component-from-json/72071475#72071475) problem, is it your question answer ?? , maybe it will help you, use it like this `

```
import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import * as Icons from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const iconList = Object.keys(Icons)
    .filter((key) => key !== 'fas' && key !== 'prefix')
    .map((icon) => Icons[icon]);

library.add(...iconList);

const Feature = ({ carFeature }) => {
    console.log(carFeature);
    return (
        <div>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={carFeature?.icon} color="#ddd" />
            <h3>{carFeature?.name}</h3>
            <p>{carFeature?.desc}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Feature;
```

If no then try this

Not the OP's direct issue but for users encountering this error for libraries not under their control, one can suppress this error is by adding:

```
{
  ...
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  ...
}
```

to the tsconfig.json file.

Read more here [Question Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358434/typescript-ts7015-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-index-expression)

Comment: Hey, the second part of the answer is a solution, but only if you want to suppress the ts error.